# Locally develop a Cython package

Tags: pip, cython, python-packaging, cythonize

I'm new at Cython, so I apologize if my question is stupid.
I'm trying to develop a package that has some functions implemented in Cython, that are called from standard python code. The structure of my package is the following:

```
my_package/
  setup.py
  build/<stuff from compilation>
  my_package/
    __init__.py
    sub/
      __init__.py
      python_code.py
      cython_code.pyx
```

In `my_code.py` I include a Cython function, using:

```
from .cython_code import cython_function
```

I think my `setup.py` is correct since I've used the Cython official doc, and when I install the package it compiles and put the results in `build/` folder.

The package I'm developing is not intended to published, I just use it for myself.
When I write pure python packages, I'm used to install in my virtual enviroment using

```
pip install -e my_package
```

so that I can edit the code without the need of reinstalling. I'm looking for an analogous for Cython. Currently, if I install the package with `-e` option, I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.sub.cython_code'
```

(actually, probably I'm missing something in the whole process of developing a Cython package)

Thanks to who is going to help me!